# Best way to compare some text files

Tags: powershell, windows-7

Here is the simplified version of the situation I'm dealing with:

- Folder `Files1` containing `a.txt`, `b.txt`, `c.txt`
- Folder `Files2` containing `a.txt`, `b.txt`, `c.txt`

I want to find the best way to compare these files. All I need to know is which files are different. For example I need to know `a.txt` is different from  `a.txt` in `Files2` folder (I don't need to know what is different inside them).

Right now I load  both in Notepad++ and use the compare function, but this is a pain.

I tried `fc`, but I'm getting cryptic output.

Comment: If you utilized some type of code repository like SVN, you could load all the files from the first folder, commit them, copy the second folder over and on commit it would show you a list of the files that are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Robocopy for that

```
robocopy c:\Temp\different\folder1 c:\temp\different\folder2 /e /l /ns /njs /njh /ndl /fp /log:c:\temp\whatIsDifferent.txt

     Newer                       c:\Temp\different\folder1\b.txt
     New File                    c:\Temp\different\folder1\d.txt
```

the key parameter is /L which allows you to "compare" instead of actually copying.

From Robocopy /? help

```
::
:: Logging Options :
::
                 /L :: List only - don't copy, timestamp or delete any files.
```

Answer (score 1):

Do a dry-run (`/l`) with [`robocopy`](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cc733145%28v=ws.10%29.aspx):

```
robocopy C:\files1 C:\files2 /njh /njs /ndl /l
```

> /l    Specifies that files are to be listed only (and not copied, deleted, or time stamped).

Answer (score 0):

Rsync can be used to do this.

```
 rsync -rvnc —delete delme/ delme2/
```

This will show you which files differ in the 2 directories.

See http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/how-to-compare-the-content-of-two-or-more-directories-automatically/ for me details.

Comment: what is the -delete flag?

Comment: OK Im using Windows .

Comment: oops - that will delete files in the target not in the source directory. Will edit that one out.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CwRsync looks to provide a windows implemention of rsync ( https://www.itefix.net/cwrsync ) but it looks commerical .. be tempting to download cygwin or use a Virtual machine perhaps.